# FLUTTER | FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I just did the installation exactly as it is written in docs.flutter.dev, created a new starter project in vs code and built it.

**I also did the same thing on my laptop and everything worked**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0.
         > C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml
   > Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0.
         > C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml
   > Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0.
         > C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml
   > Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\ghost\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\230823a14f0dec17db3869ef1998e574\transformed\core-1.6.0.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             97.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

- I tried to run on **android studio**
- **flutter doctor** command showed that everything was **fine**
- tried `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get`

**It's still the same error.**